# python3 variable type declaration syntax error

Tags: python-3.x

Why does the `:` syntax not work on linux

**On MacOS**

```
→ python3
Python 3.6.3 (default, Oct  4 2017, 06:09:38) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.37)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> x : str = "hello"
>>>
```

**On Linux**

```
→ python3
Python 3.5.3 (default, Jan 19 2017, 14:11:04) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170118] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> x : str = "hello"
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    x : str = "hello"
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

Comment: What makes you think the OS has anything to do with what version of Python you have installed?

Comment: I've 3.5.2 and I can't get it to work on MacOS.. seems like it is something to do with the version of python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its the version of python that is causing this. Update to 3.6 on Linux as well. Check release notes

[Whats new in 3.6](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html)

Answer (score 2):

It is the problem with the python version.
Try the same with 3.6 in linux.